# Request count per second in a linux port

Tags: linux, shell, http, tcp

I am in an emergency situation and I need the count of request in a linux port.

Request will be HTTP GET and port is 7003. How I can get request count per second?

Comment: There are lot of tools available for network monitoring. You can use `tcpdump` to capture on a particular port for particular request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -c :7003
```

This should give you an idea of what you have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Network sniffer is one way to do that.

Wireshark is a free network sniffer.

With Wireshark you can use the following display filter to show only HTTP-GET requests:

```
http.request.method == "GET"
```

You can limit amount of captured traffic by using a capture filter. For getting TCP port 7003 traffic only, you can use the capture filter:

```
tcp port 7003
```

Then the statistics summary dialog of Wireshark shows the wanted value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use watch and netstat like below:

```
watch netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -c ':7003$'
```

Default watch run that command per second.

Comment: It will never return request per second but will return how many clients are connected at that time.